# SQL Server - What is the difference between BULKADMIN and ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS

Tags: sql-server, permissions, bulk-insert

To grant user ability to run `Bulk Insert T-SQL command`, login/user needs to be granted:

1. `BULKADMIN` server role - or - `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` server-level permission
2. connect on target database
3. insert on target table

But what is the difference between `BULKADMIN` server role and `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` server-level permission ?

Comment: `exec sys.sp_srvrolepermission 'bulkadmin'` implies that one potential difference might be the ability to add other bulkadmins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the [SQL Server Permissions Poster (2017 edition)](https://aka.ms/sql-permissions-poster):

[image]

It appears as though `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` covers [bulkadmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15#fixed-server-level-roles) in addition to [`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which allows access to external sources.